# Will having ClassA extend ClassB slow down my runtime performance compared to having classC which contains all the members of ClassC?

Tags: java, performance, memory, inheritance

I have a class with a lot of methods. I would like to group similar methods together in their own class, but *all* of the methods need to extend another class, *ClassC*. So I was thinking of having *ClassA*, which contains the first group of methods, extend *ClassB*, which extends Class_C, etc.

Is this inefficient in terms of runtime performance, or are they virtually the same?

Note: there will be hundreds of instances of this class running at once, so I would really not want to waste memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically virtual methods will slow a program down because a runtime check is performed to decide which method to use. However you should consider these things before worrying about it:

1. I have very little info on your classes so if the extending doesn't make the code more readable you shouldn't do it.
2. All methods must be virtual in java so I would guess they have highly optimized the runtime dispatching of them.
3. Lastly you won't know how much the program is slowed down until you actually try it, generally worrying about small optimizations before you need to optimize is a bad idea

A couple more things that require some assumption on my part:

1. "100's" is a **very** small number in software engineering, you likely won't see any performance slowdown at that few objects
2. While multiple extension might not slow down your program in general programmers like to save inheritance for ***is-a*** relationships, in your situation it might be better to use [composition](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example) instead of inheritance

Comment: +1 - The calls are extremely optimized by the JIT - and if you keep methods small and interfaces simple you tend to get methods inlined and monomorphically dispatched anyhow (no/less lookups).